# Can someone explain this linear dependence proof to me?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

[image]

I'm not sure how the pink equation is transitioned to the ice blue equation. Where does the $c_{j}$ denominator go in each scalar?

And where exactly does the -1 scalar come from to finalize the proof for linear dependence?

Comment: The pink equation is not transformed into the blue equation. They are independent.  Note the word "conversely."  The $-1$ comes from subtracting $v_j$ from both sides of the blue equation.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but how is this a linear dependence proof if we are "supposing it is" in the beginning sentence. (Im new to proofs)

Comment: What exactly is the statement of the theorem?

Comment: Proof can be found here (Theorem 7) http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~sellerme/sfehtml/classes/math3260/miscellaneousproofs06232010.pdf

Comment: Notice that the theorem says "if and only if," so there are really two statements to prove.  (The word "conversely" separates the two proofs.)  In one of them, you assume the vectors are linearly dependent.  In the other, you must prove that they linearly dependent.  You can prove this by contradiction, by assuming they are not linearly dependent.